# Unable to fetch data from Model.findByID in Node - Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch data from mongodb into my NodeJS project. I'm able to get the whole list of documents and as well as able to post to the database too. But I'm unable to fetch a particular data using the ObjectID of the collection. I'm using Mongoose.Model to fetch the data:

This is my function to fetch data:

```
exports.findOne = async (req, res) => {
    await Note.findById(ObjectId(req.params.noteId))
    .then(note => {
        if(!note) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Note not found with id " + req.params.noteId
            });            
        }
        res.send(note);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Note not found with id " + req.params.noteId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Error retrieving note with id " + req.params.noteId
        });
    });
}
```

This is my Model schema:

```
const noteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    content:String,
    author:String,
    createdAt:{
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
})
```

This is the route portion:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()

const notes = require('../controller/notesController')

router.get('/',notes.getNotes)
router.post('/',notes.createNote)
router.get('/notes/:noteId', (...args) => notes.findOne(...args));


module.exports = router
```

In the index.js :

```
app.use('/notes',notesRoute)
```

When I enter `http://localhost:5000/notes/60e400256a680b3c44f83208` it didn't fetch the data and return the following error message in POSTMAN:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /notes/60e400256a680b3c44f83208</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: please, add also the code where you define the route. It might be the issue is there

Comment: @SergeyReus yep added it

Comment: You can try to pass id as a string, without converting it to ObjectId

Comment: @NikitaMazur for that also it remains same

Comment: @Thiluxan if you could share the whole file with routes...it could be that you define the route before express initialized

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem with your route. Check your route file you might have missed anything. Postman shows this error when the route is invalid.

Comment: but it works for fetching all documents and adding a new document

Answer (score 0):

You should import express from the index.js file in your routes. Example: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/multi-router/controllers/api_v1.js

And !Important thing: route must be:

```
router.get('/:noteId', notes.findOne);
```

because you already set the initial route here

```
app.use('/notes',notesRoute)
```

In your current implementation correct URL is `http://localhost:5000/notes/notes/60e400256a680b3c44f83208`

Also, I would suggest you not mix promises and async/await.

You could use async/await:

```
try {
  const note = await Note.findById(req.params.noteId);
  if (!note) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      message: "Note not found with id " + req.params.noteId
    });
  }
  res.send(note)
} catch (e) {
//handle error here
}
```

Or Promises:

```
Note.findById(req.params.noteId).then(note => {
//handle note
}).catch(error => {
//handle error
})
```